# MySQL Where IS NOT ALL NULL?

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause

How can a query with ability to verify all selected records are not null?
For example with the following query,
verify all rows with field `is_field_null` is not `NULL` from returned `level1`?

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT tb_a.A, tb_b.is_field_null FROM tb_a, tb_b, tb_c
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
AND tb_a.b = tb_b.a
AND tb_c.b = tb_b.c
) AS level1
```

Suppose there are some rows with `is_field_null` in `level1` are indeed `NULL` and the tables are

tb_a

```
a          |    b        |      A
------------------------------------------
"some"     | "thing"     | "XXX"
"some"     | "thing"     | "YYY"
```

tb_b

```
a            | c           | is_field_null 
----------------------------------------------
"thing"       | "else"      | "I have things here" 
"thing"       | "else"      | NULL
```

tb_c

```
b            | c           | mapper 
----------------------------------------------
"else"       | "else"      | "ZZZ" 
"else"       | "else"      | "KKK"
```

I have tried the following which it returns some row(s) with `is_field_null` is not null. E.g.

```sql
A        |     is_field_null
-----------------------------
"XXX"    | "I have things here"
"YYY"    | "I have things here"
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT tb_a.A, tb_b.is_field_null FROM tb_a, tb_b, tb_c
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
AND tb_a.b = tb_b.a
AND tb_c.b = tb_b.c
) AS level1
WHERE level1.is_field_null IS NOT NULL
```

I would expect an empty table. How can I do it?

E.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT tb_a.A, tb_b.is_field_null FROM tb_a, tb_b, tb_c
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
AND tb_a.b = tb_b.a
AND tb_c.b = tb_b.c
) AS level1
WHERE level1.is_field_null IS NOT ALL NULL ??
```

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, a simple method uses window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tb_a.A,
        tb_b.is_field_null,
        MAX(tb_b.is_field_null IS NULL) has_null
    FROM tb_a 
    INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
    INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
    WHERE 
        tb_a.a = 'some' 
        AND tb_a.b = 'thing' 
        AND tb_c.c = 'else'
) t
WHERE has_null = 0
```

Note that this uses standard, explicit joins rather than old-school, implicit joins - this ancient syntax should not be used in new code.

Also I would recommend single quotes instead of double quotes for literal strings (this is the MySQL syntax).